# apply an adjustment to each series depending on column name

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, conditional-statements

I'm working with time series data. Each column label is a year.

I want to selectively apply an adjustment, depending on the year.

The following returns an adjustment of 0.5 across all years/columns. How can I apply the adjusted factor in the early years?

```
for year in df_difference.columns: 
    if year < (2020):
        z = (((year - 2010) / (2020)) * 100) 
        adjusted_factor = z * 0.50
    else:
        adjusted_factor = 0.50

#Need to apply the appropriate factor to each item in the series (series/column name = year)
df_incremental_difference = df_difference.mul(adjusted_factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for year in df_difference.columns: 
    if year < (2020):
        z = (((year - 2010) / (2020)) * 100) 
        adjusted_factor = z * 0.50
    else:
        adjusted_factor = 0.50

    df_difference.loc[year].mul(adjusted_factor)
```

Comment: Hi @Guinther Kovalski. Thanks for taking a look. Unfortunately, I get the error: cannot set a row with mismatched columns. I'll keep trying.

Comment: if you could provide some input/ouput examples i'm really sure we can help you (:

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :) Thanks Guinther, your answer helped me.

```
for year in df_difference.columns:
    if year < 2020:
        z = (((year - 2010) / (2020)) * 100) 

    else:
        z = 1.0

    adjusted_factor = z * 0.50
    df_difference[year] = df_difference[year] * adjusted_factor
    print(year, z, adjusted_factor)
```